# Template strnlen mess

Tags: c++

I have a function accepting a variable of any type. Now, **if** the variable is `char*` or `const char*`, I need to know the length. How to do this?

The function bellow doesn't compile. `subscript requires array or pointer type`

```
template <typename Type>
unsigned long get_len(Type in)
{
   unsigned long i = 0;
   while (in[i]) ++i;
   return i;
}
```

Comment: If the function can accept a variable of *any* type then why do you only need to know the length if it's a string?

Comment: I handle each type differently if it's string-like and differently if it's int-like

Comment: [Compiles fine for me.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/220d4f5ead77e94b) Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? Without being able to reproduce your error, nobody will be able to give you an accurate answer.

Comment: If the only types you're handling are strings and ints then you don't need templates at all, just multiple overloads of a function (or different functions)

Comment: I am handling many types (long, unsigned int, int etc)

Comment: What should `get_len` return for an `int`?

Comment: I won't run it for an int. It can return 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compilation failure occurs when the template is **instantiated**.

Presumably this function is potentially called from within other template code, something like:

```
template <typename Type>
void f(Type in)
{
   unsigned l = get_len(in);
   // etc.
}
char* s= "hi";
f(s); // Compiles OK.
int i = 0;
f(i); // Compile failure.
```

The issue is therefore that `get_len` makes no sense when `Type` is not an array type, and you should not call it from other instantiations of the template.

As noted elsewhere, the solution is for the base template to not call `get_len`.

You can then create either a template specialization or just a plain overload which handles the `char*` case and calls `get_len(char*)`, which does not then need to be a template.

Answer (score 1):

When defining a templated function, it's OK to overload it with a non-templated function.  So for your function that needs to handle char* differently, overload it.

eg:

```
void AnyTypeFunction(char* type);
```

and

```
template<typename Type> void AnyTypeFunction(Type type);
```

Comment: I am still unable to see how this answers the question if the OP refuses to show his usage that gives a compiler error.

Comment: I'm answering the question in the OP: "I have a function accepting a variable of any type. Now, if the variable is char* or const char*, I need to know the length. How to do this?"
His function won't compile unless you never try to call get_len with an int.

Comment: You mean it will compile if you don't call it with an int.

Comment: That means the same thing, except it's obvious the OP tried to call it with an int.

Comment: No it doesn't mean the same thing. It's a double negative.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't not mean the same thing.

Comment: You mean "it does mean the same thing." Your continued use of double negatives makes me question if you understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

Well the error itself is easy to solve, just template upon `Type*`, which means ptr to any type like this:

```
unsigned long get_len(Type* in)
```

However, you are going to have much worse problems later on, seeing how this will fail badly with strings that aren't null terminated. (+ It will accept any array, which usually aren't null terminated and so on.)

Really, properly constraining template types is relatively advanced topic and judging by the comments, what you want to do isn't a good idea.